# How do I resolve 'Unexpected number of row removed!'?

Tags: mysql, sequelpro, database-management

I'm trying to delete all row of data in my tables and reset the auto increment.  When I do, I get this message :

```
Unexpected number of rows removed!

One row was not removed. Reload the table to be sure that the contents
have not changed in the meantime. Check the Console for possible errors 
inside the primary keys of this table!
```

**update**
When I do TRUNCATE TABLE 'users' I get this message

```
    Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
 (`marketing`.`designer_application`, CONSTRAINT
 `designer_application_user_id_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES 
`marketing`.`users` (`id`))
```

Comment: Truncate tablename; There is also a item in the Menu

Comment: This will help you to decide
Visit: <http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61240/difference-between-drop-and-truncate>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely another process acted on the same rows that you selected before you were able to delete them. If you are using the UI to delete the rows, consider using a SQL query instead. Using [`TRUNCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html) will clear the contents of a table and reset the `auto increment` to `0`.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `tablename`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with tables that have FOREIGN KEY constraints, using `DELETE FROM tablename` is preferable over `TRUNCATE TABLE`. The `DELETE` command will also remove corresponding entries from tables that have a foreign key relationship with it.

Alternatively, you can temporarily disable the foreign key constraints by running:

```sql
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

However, be aware that this won't remove associated data from other tables.

If you encounter an error message saying "Unexpected number of rows removed!" when trying to delete rows, it could be due to table locks. You can identify and terminate these locking queries as follows:

To find the queries that are locking the table:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE DB = 'DATABASE_NAME'
```

To generate 'KILL' commands for these queries:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('KILL ',id,';') SEPARATOR ' ') FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE user = 'DATABASE_NAME'
```

After obtaining the 'KILL' queries, execute them to remove the table locks.